# What was Steve? Is it called something else now?

Tags: atmosphere, planetary-science, physics, magnetic-field, magnetosphere

"Steve" was a temporary name for a space phenomenon above the Earth. Since then it's likely much work as been done and a more permanent name chosen. So I'd like to ask what Steve really was/is, and if it is now named differently.

Background, asked almost exactly three years ago:

- [Could Steve have hurt the ISS?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21219/12102)
- [If Steve is at 300 km, and SWARM is >440km, how did SWARM measure Steve's temperature?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21244/12102)

Comment: It's still called STEVE, now a backronym: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_(atmospheric_phenomenon)

Comment: @amI hmm... do you think there;s enough known for an answer, or maybe I should delete this and post it again in a few years?

Comment: @amI I've just asked [What is electron precipitation? Why would STEVE care?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46544/12102)